# Adding Angular 2 (click) attribute globally to CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

In Angular 1, you could simply add

```
[ngClick],
[data-ng-click],
[x-ng-click] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and all tags with the `ng-click` attribute would now have the pointer cursor now. How can we add the Angular 2 `(click)` attribute in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible using just the name of an attribute.  Angular 2 changes this template:

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <div (click)="sayhi()"></div>
</div>
```

to this DOM:

```
 <div _ngcontent-xwy-0="">
     <h2 _ngcontent-xwy-0="">Hello Angular2</h2>
     <div _ngcontent-xwy-0=""></div>
  </div>
```

Since there is no way to specify a wildcard attribute name CSS selector (i.e. `[_ngcontent-*] { cursor: pointer }`, there is no way to achieve this using just CSS.

Comment: That makes sense. I hope there is some way to work around this in the future.

Comment: You can disable view encapsulation. Then it is possible. Not sure that's desired though.

Answer (score -2):

`<div href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="sayhi()"></div>`

Comment: This does not really answer the question; the question is about styling an element that has the `(click)` pseudo attribute on it, using CSS.